# Wildfly Swarm runs a deployed artifact using it's hash name

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-swarm

I have a standard clean web project that I'm using to build a Wildfly swarm artifact. My POM looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test.swarm</groupId>
    <artifactId>test_security_module</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom-all</artifactId>
                <version>2017.6.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-swarm-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2017.6.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I also have a jboss-web.xml that is supposed to register a context root, and looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_6_0.xsd"
           version="6.0">

    <context-root>/Tiles</context-root>

</jboss-web>
```

So after building and running the project, the /Tiles context root must be registered, and the application accessible on: http://localhost:8080/Tiles.

But then I try to run the uber jar using the standard java -jar, Swarm deploys the hash name of the project name (as opposed to the project name). It doesn't even register the context root. The snippet of the stack trace is:

> 2017-07-04 04:32:14,329 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Swarm 2017.6.1 (WildFly Core 2.2.1.Final) started in 5762ms - Started 55 of 59 services (4 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
>   2017-07-04 04:32:14,383 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm.runtime.deployer] (main) deploying 3d31f81a-29d6-4ea1-b3eb-0a2a98a3c3f5.war
>   2017-07-04 04:32:14,405 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "3d31f81a-29d6-4ea1-b3eb-0a2a98a3c3f5.war" (runtime-name: "3d31f81a-29d6-4ea1-b3eb-0a2a98a3c3f5.war")
>   2017-07-04 04:32:14,464 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (main) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "3d31f81a-29d6-4ea1-b3eb-0a2a98a3c3f5.war" (runtime-name : "3d31f81a-29d6-4ea1-b3eb-0a2a98a3c3f5.war")
>   2017-07-04 04:32:14,466 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM99999: WildFly Swarm is Ready

What could cause swarm to run the application using the hash name of the project?

Comment: Not something I've seen unless you have a custom main() creating an archive with no name, which doesn't appear to be your situation.

Could you raise an issue for it? https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SWARM

Comment: Managed to fix it by adding                 
                                                            
 <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
 <artifactId>undertow</artifactId>                                                             
                                                                                                                  That error is very cryptic

Comment: Actually it makes sense, apologies I didn't notice that yesterday. If you want to deploy a WAR, you need either `undertow` or `jaxrs` for that to work

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding the undertow dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
    <artifactId>undertow</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it by starting swarm/thorntail as this way:

```
Swarm swarm = new Swarm();
swarm.start();
WARArchive a = ShrinkWrap.create(WARArchive.class, "WARNAME");
swarm.deploy(a);
```

Where WARNAME is, obviously, the name of the ".war" you want.

Thorntail version: 2.2.0.Final

PS:  It jus can change the hash to a file name...
I think you need to put the files into before deploy... I couldn't find how to do it.
I was trying to run an EJB Stateless with a jndi lookup with de the name "java:/global" + runtime-name + "/EJBname".  and when I run it in Swarm I need to know the hash...
So, What I did?

```
   Swarm conteiner = new Swarm();   
   Archive a = conteiner.createDefaultDeployment();
   a.getId();  // where id is the hash
```

I'm trying to put this hash in the lookup.